# iOS 8 Widget unit testing

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest, ios8-extension

I tried to create a testing bundle for my widget but it always failed when launching test. At firs, I was trying to create testing bundle as copy of my existing containing app testing bundle and modify proper build settings. Then I was trying to create testing bundle by adding target in project settings through target wizard and then I noticed that when you are choosing tested target that you can't choose widget target. So, is it possible to test iOS 8 widget with XCtest or Kiwi framework? Is there any workaround or hack to test widgets on iOS 8?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the steps you used to create your widget within your application please.

Comment: @DanielStormApps, widget was created by completing simply theese steps: http://tinyurl.com/ny8lmhu

Comment: Pages 14-22 of this document may be what you're looking for. It sounds like you have not created your widget properly. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensibilityPG.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to see this article?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW8

Specifically, quoting Apple, "To test an app extension using the Xcode testing framework (that is, the XCTest APIs), write tests that exercise the extension code using your containing app as the host environment..."

If you've learned any new nuggets since you posted this then please share your truths with the community.